# Assigning x:Name to Thickness throws exception

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Can anyone explain why this throws an exception?

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Margin>
            <Thickness x:Name="thickness" />
        </Grid.Margin>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I remove the `x:Name` attribute, then it runs successfully.

Error details:

> Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
>   Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError
>   Message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at SilverlightBindingTest.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
>      at SilverlightBindingTest.MainPage..ctor()
>      at SilverlightBindingTest.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
>      at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
>      at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Name attribute is a DependencyObject and as such can only be set on another DependencyObject.

Thickness is not a DependencyObject, so you cannot use the Name attribute.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a bummer, I was hoping to animate a margin -- apparently not possible.

Comment: You can only animate Dependency Properties, so you can change the margin with a storyboard, but it cant be animated. You might want to consider Scale and/or Translate transforms to achieve a similar effect. Or you could animate Height, Width, Top, Left, Right and Bottom to achieve the same.

Comment: Ah right ... the "discrete animation using keyframes", I guess.